# If condition Inside fetch_array

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Good day, Please check my script first.

```
$fields = $query->list_fields();

foreach($query->result_array() as $data){
    if($row % 2 == 0){
        //blabla
    }
    $col = 1;
    foreach ($fields as $field){    
        if($data[$field]['Stats'] == 0){ //In this part

        }               
    }
    $row++;
    $no++;
}
```

So, i want to check specified field that named with `Stats`. My Problem is how i do `If Conditional statement there`. Because with my script above i always get false.

result when i print `$data`

```
Array
(
    [Kode Otlet] => K-BDCW2
    [Area] => BANDUNG
    [Nip] => 1500029
    [Nama Lengkap] => AHMAD ILHAM YUSUP
    [Posisi Sebelumnya] => VMO
    [Posisi Baru] => VMO
    [Tanggal Upgrade/Demosi] => 2016-06-03
    [Stats] => 0
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 7
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 7
)
```

Comment: We don't know about `$fields` and `$data`. What are they clarify first.

Comment: that variable(s) come from `sql query`

Comment: How your `$data` looks like?? can you give us the sample??

Comment: May be its something like: `if($data[$field] == 'Stats'){ //do }`

Comment: I've update my question

Comment: simply do $data['Stats'] == 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need to use the `$fields`, Without `$fields` you can do it like:

```
if($data['Stats'] == 0){ //do }
```

Or, if your want to use `$fields` then you need to double check the condition like:

```
if($data[$field] == 0 && $field == 'Stats'){ //do }
```